# Thymeleaf multiple ternary operator with OR condition

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, conditional-operator

With Thymeleaf I am using this (it works fine):

```
<li class="drop-down" th:classappend="${#httpServletRequest.getRequestURI() == '/url1' ? 'active':''}"><a href="#">MainMenu</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="/url1" th:href="@{/url1}"><i
class="fas fa-users"></i> url1</a></li>
<li><a href="/url2" th:href="@{/url2}"><i
class="fas fa-users"></i> url2</a></li>
<li><a href="/url3" th:href="@{/url3}"><i
class="far fa-file-alt mr-1"></i> url3</a></li>
<li><a href="/url4" th:href="@{/url4}"><i
class="fas fa-sign-out-alt mr-1"></i>url4</a></li>
</ul></li>
```

Now I want to set the active class to the main menu if any of the URL 1/2/3/4 is clicked. So I tried this (And it did NOT work):

```
<li class="drop-down" th:classappend="${#httpServletRequest.getRequestURI() == '/url1' ? 'active':'' :: '/url2' ? 'active':'' :: '/url3' ? 'active':'' :: '/url4' ? 'active':'' }"
```

Also I tried  a lot other combination with "or" and "||", nothing worked. All these URLs (context paths) are totally different and I CAN NOT use like - contains. I am sure I am missing the idea, but need some help here. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to append the `active` class when request URI matches any from a set of fixed values. So you can write your `<li>` element like this:

```html
<li
   class="drop-down"
   th:with="urls=${new String[]{'/url1','/url2','/url3','/url4'}}"
   th:classappend="${#arrays.contains(urls, #httpServletRequest.getRequestURI()) ? 'active' : ''}">
```

...where:

- `th:with` declares an array named `urls` containing urls which triggers appending of a class.
- `th:classappend` checks whether the `urls` array contains a value returned by `#httpServletRequest.getRequestURI()` and conditionally appends a class.

Comment: Thanks Jakub. Either I am doing something wrong or you have a typo. Bcoz, `th:with="urls="${` does not work while this works - `th:with="urls=${`. It is an additional double-quotes you mistyped or I am still doing it wrong?

Comment: @AjayKumar Yeah, I've mistyped the double-quotes by accident. Good catch :)